# start on emit is not working on upstart

Tags: debian, services, autorun, upstart

I am working to restart service if stopped.

I was looking for [`upstart`](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/getting-started.html), to restart service. I found some [answers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/409991/upstart-job-works-only-with-manual-start-stop).

I took `apache2` service for testing. I changed code as below.

```
# File : /etc/init.d/apache2
...
...
#
# Function that stops the daemon/service
#
do_stop()
{
        # Return
        #   0 if daemon has been stopped
        #   1 if daemon was already stopped
        #   2 if daemon could not be stopped
        #   other if a failure occurred

        # either "stop" or "graceful-stop"
        local STOP=$1
        # can't use pidofproc from LSB here
        local AP_RET=0

        # send stopping apache event
        echo "Stopping....."
        initctl emit stopping-apache2

        if pidof $DAEMON > /dev/null 2>&1 ; then
                if [ -e $PIDFILE ] && pidof $DAEMON | tr ' ' '\n' | grep -w $(cat $PIDFILE) > /dev/null 2>&1 ; then
                        AP_RET=2
                else
                        AP_RET=1
                fi
        else
            AP_RET=0
        fi

        # AP_RET is:
        # 0 if Apache (whichever) is not running
        # 1 if Apache (whichever) is running
        # 2 if Apache from the PIDFILE is running

        if [ $AP_RET = 0 ] ; then
                # send stopping apache event
                echo "Stopped.....1"
                initctl emit stopped-apache2

                return 1
        fi

        if [ $AP_RET = 2 ] && apache_conftest ; then
                $APACHE2CTL $STOP > /dev/null 2>&1
                apache_wait_stop $?
                # send stopping apache event
                echo "Stopped.....2"
                initctl emit stopped-apache2
                return $?
        else
                if [ $AP_RET = 2 ]; then
                                        clear_error_msg
                        APACHE2_INIT_MESSAGE="The apache2$DIR_SUFFIX configtest failed, so we are trying to kill it manually. This is almost certainly suboptimal, so please make sure your system is working as you'd expect now!"
                        killproc -p $PIDFILE $DAEMON
                        apache_wait_stop $?
                        # send stopping apache event
                        echo "Stopped.....3"
                        initctl emit stopped-apache2
                        return $?
                elif [ $AP_RET = 1 ] ; then
                        APACHE2_INIT_MESSAGE="There are processes named 'apache2' running which do not match your pid file which are left untouched in the name of safety, Please review the situation by hand".
                        # send stopping apache event
                        echo "Stopped.....4"
                        initctl emit stopped-apache2
                        return 2
                fi
        fi

}
...
...
```

**Note**: emit message using `initctl emit stopped-apache2`

Then changed `apache2.conf` to perform start operation on this event.

```
# File /etc/init/apache2.conf
# apache2
# the purpose of this job is
# * start apache2 in upstart rather than SysV startup

start on stopped-apache2
stop on runlevel [016]


pre-start script
export RUNLEVEL=2
[ -f /var/lib/apache2.enable ] && /etc/init.d/apache2 start
end script

post-stop exec /etc/init.d/apache2 stop
```

When I stop apache I got message.

```
root@localhost:~# /etc/init.d/apache2 stop
[....] Stopping web server: apache2Stopping.....
Stopped.....2
. ok
```

But seems its not executing `start on stopped-apache2`.

I also restart job using `initctl restart apache2`.

I missed something ?